# Google colab wont render blender animations anymore. Always getting: Failed to create CUDA context (Unknown error)

Tags: rendering, scripting

Im using [this](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10KDxTUnfSBcLt9-a8F6GmNxfew1d-EeB#scrollTo=MoNkweWtMm-C) notebook to try and render an animation using google colab. It was working fine a week ago but now i cant even render a single frame because it keeps giving me the error. Is there any way to fix it?